# Number of states of a finite automaton recognizing all words beginning with some fixed string $x$

Tags: formal-languages, automata

For a string $x \in \{a,b\}^\ast$ with $|x| = n$, how many states are required for an FA accepting the language of all strings in $\{a,b\}$ that begin with $x$? For each of these states, describe the strings that cause the FA to be in that state.

---

So $x$ looks like any combination of $a$'s and $b$'s right? Is the answer two because $x$ could begin with $a$ or $b$, and those are both accepted in the language of all strings in $\{a,b\}$?

Comment: According to your problem statement, $x$ is a **string** ($x \in \{a,b\}^\ast$). Take for example $x = ab$. How would you construct an FA accepting (exactly) those strings $y$ beginning with $x$? What would you do in the case $x = aaa$? What for $x = abab$? Do you see the pattern?

Comment: Please improve your question by including additional context, such as where you encountered the problem. This will help others write better and more helpful answers.

Comment: I expect this is a homework question (at least it sounds like one and the solution is really not that hard), so the comment left by PhoemueX should be enough. It gives a clue how to solve the problem, without stating the actual solution.

Comment: To go on comment 1, I would make an initial state that requires an a to move forward, then a b to move again. Any state other than those afterward would not change an accepted state. Any alterations before a then b that occur though would throw it off into a permanent unaccepted state. I still don't get the answer to the question though....